# Linux system waits for 90 seconds after "poweroff" is invoked before shutdown in VMware

Tags: linux, vmware, shutdown, archlinux

I am running Arch Linux (installed from `archlinux-2014.01.05-dual.iso`) on VMware Player and have installed `vmtoolsd` (which belongs to `open-vm-tools`).

Now my problem is that, whenever I do `poweroff` or `reboot`, the system just leaves me with a black screen with only a cursor flashing at the top-left corner. If I don't do anything to it, the system will shutdown or reboot in one or two minutes.

I've searched Google for this problem. Some people suggest that I modify `/usr/lib/systemd/system/vmtoolsd.service` and that I add one line for `KillSignal=SIGKILL` or `TimeoutStopSec=2`. However, none of these works. Actually when I do `systemctl stop vmtoolsd`, it seems to stop quickly.

I guess maybe some other service is in the similar state as is discussed in those posts I see. Is there a workaround on this so that I can shutdown my virtual machine immediately and gracefully, or that I can figure out what is going on during `poweroff` is executing so that I can tell if any service is blocked?

Update March 4, 2014: Now the problem becomes strange. I reinstalled Arch Linux but the problem just continues. Now I guess that it may not necessarily be a problem of `vmtoolsd` or any service I installed, but of VMware tools or the system. (But I am sure that Ubuntu does not have this problem running in VMware.) Now I am trying to figure out what really caused the problem.

By the way, is there any report that Arch Linux or other system based on that has similar issue when running in VMware?

Update March 4, 2014: I used Arch Linux Live CD and similar problem happens with error message: **A stop job is running for User Manager for 0**. Then I thought this might be a bug which is reported here: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=70593 which is a bug of `systemd` and was fixed in update 209 or 210. I then did an update using `pacman -Syu` and the delay was gone. However, I think I have updated my Arch Linux last time when I have `open-vm-tools` installed (before I reinstall the entire system). Now I plan to install `open-vm-tools` again and see if the same error occurs.

Comment: Isn't that a question for http://serverfault.com/ or http://superuser.com/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've installed some services or programs that take some time to stop, you could investigate on this (`ps`, `top` commands) or simply kill everything (see `xkill`) before try to sudo halt. Also if you are using internet and downloading/installing many programs you should either take a look at RK Hunter or something similar.

Hope this helps

regards,

LX

Comment: Sorry for my incomplete information. After I asked the question, I reinstalled Arch Linux but the problem continues. I guess it may not be a problem of any installed service after Arch is installed. I am trying to turn off some features in VMware and try if it solves the problem. By the way, is it OK that I don't install `vmtoolsd` or any equivalence? If I don't get VMware Tools, how can I drive the virtual graphic card for X?

Comment: You should install vmware tools (guest addition or i don't know something like that) for better performance. But, I don't know how to proceed with arch, could yo access / mount a CD-ROM if yes in vmware there is an option in the file/menu to mount the tools

Comment: Actually it is quite hard to install the official VMware Tools in Arch Linux. I tried it and installed a lot of dependencies but still end up failed. However, my issue seems to have a second possibility which is a bug of `systemd`. I will update the question soon. Now after re-installation and system update, the problem is not reproduced yet.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you describe is a [bug](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=70593). I have personally seen this bug on a Virtualbox machine. I can't really help you much more. Hopefully, it will be fixed soon. Take care.